# Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $R$. Show $IJ$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.

For ideals $I$, $J \in R$ define $IJ$ to be the set 
$\{a_1b_1 +\ldots+a_nb_n : n\in\mathbb N$; $a_i\in I$; $b_j \in J\}.$

Prove that $IJ$ is an ideal in $R$.

Comment: To see that any subset of a ring is an ideal, you must show it is closed under addition, and under multiplication by any element in the ring.  Try starting with two arbitrary elements in $IJ$ (like the one you wrote down in defining the set), and see if their sum has the same form.  Next, see if when you multiply one of these elements by some $r\in R$, you can still write it in the desired form.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $I, J$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$. We show $IJ = \{i_1j_1 + i_2j_2 + \cdots + i_nj_n\ : i_k \in I,\, j_k \in J,\, n \in \mathbb Z^+ \}$ is also an ideal.

We must first show that $IJ$ is an additive subgroup of $R$. Observe that $0 \in I$ and $0 \in J$ since each are ideals and therefore additive subgroups of $R$. Thus $0 \cdot 0 = 0 \in IJ \neq \emptyset$. Now let $x \in IJ$. then $x = i_1j_1 + i_2j_2 + \cdots + i_nj_n$ for some $i_k \in I$, $j_k \in J$ and $n \in \mathbb Z^+$. Observe that since $i_k \in I$ and $I$ is an additive subgroup of $R$ by definition of ideal then $-i_k \in I$ and thus 
                \begin{align*}
     (-i_1)j_1 + (-i_2)j_2 + \cdots + (-i_n)j_n &=  -i_1j_1 - i_2j_2 - \cdots - i_nj_n \\
     &= -( i_1j_1 + i_2j_2 + \cdots + i_nj_n) \\
     &= -x \in IJ
    \end{align*}
                Now let $x, y \in IJ$ then $x = i_1j_1 + i_2j_2 + \cdots + i_nj_n$ and $y = i_1'j_1' + i_2'j_2' + \cdots + i_{n'}'j_{n'}'$ for some $i_k, i_k' \in I$, $j_k, j_k' \in J$ and $n, n' \in \mathbb Z^+$. Then $$x + y =\big( i_1j_1 + i_2j_2 + \cdots + i_nj_n\big) + \big( i_1'j_1' + i_2'j_2' + \cdots + i_{n'}'j_{n'}'\big) \in IJ$$ Thus we have shown that $IJ$ is an additive subgroup of $R$.

Now let $r \in R$ and $a \in IJ$ where $i_1j_1 + i_2j_2 + \cdots + i_nj_n$. Observe that $ra = r(i_1j_1 + i_2j_2 + \cdots + i_nj_n) = ri_1j_1 + ri_2j_2 + \cdots + ri_nj_n$ and since $ri_k \in I$ since $I$ is an ideal we an conclude that $ra \in IJ$ and thus $IJ$ is a left ideal.

Since $R$ is commutative $IJ$ is also a right ideal.

This by definition $IJ$ is an ideal of $R$

Comment: In $x+y$, there are two different $n$'s used.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I will fix it!

Comment: @Robert When $R$ is commutative every ideal is two-sided, so one paragraph is redundant.